# Resume my android app from Notification bar (and app icon still shows in bar)

Tags: android, notifications, pause

I want to resume my app, exactly at where I left from notification icon in bar. Then I used this code:

```
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_speed)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.txt_welcome))
            .setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setOngoing(true);
    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

It works well, the issue is when I press the icon in notification bar, it disappears, I need it to stay there.

Of course, if I delete these three lines:

```
resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

in manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleInstance"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

the icon won't disappear after clicking on it, but I always redirect to MainActivity, not the same place I left (when app got into pause).

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting :

```
setAutoCancel(false)
```

Reference : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setAutoCancel(boolean)

Hope it helps !

**Edit** :

As per discussion, need to set in manifest :

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

This will deliver new intent to "onNewIntent" function which can be used to do further actions in case your activity was already running.

Comment: Thank you Abhinav, it was the problem source, but now it doesn't go back to where I was before pause :-| It always starts mainActivity from clicking notification :-( any idea?

Comment: It starts mainActivity because, the intent passed to it has activity as MainActivity, see your first line : "Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);". Don't you want to start with main activity always ? What behaviour is expected, if app was not running initially and notification is pressed and, if app was running with some other activity and notification was pressed ?

Comment: I found the issue :) I already set android:launchMode="singleInstance" for MainActivity in manifest.xml, I removed it and it works like a charm, thanks for your help :)

Comment: because of these two lines, I should go back to where i left :) resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

Comment: But still it would always start MainActivity, right ??

Comment: you need is : android:launchMode="singleTop", this will deliver new intent to "onNewIntent" function which can be used to do further actions in case your activity was already running.

Comment: yes, exactly :) thank you, I accepted your answer, so could you please add this line android:launchMode="singleTop" to your answer for others to see the true answer :)

Comment: Okay, I have added.

Comment: it is perfect now :) Thank you, you saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Notification should be onGoing

```
mBuilder.setOngoing(true); //this will make ongoing notification
```

Comment: ok. sorry. Did you try setAutocancel(false) ? you set it to true.

Comment: setAutoCancel(false) should work, I have answered below with reference.

Comment: @Rafal thank you, it was the problem of not showing the icon :)

Comment: @par4301 make this (or other one)  accepted answer, so others could find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

please refer below example and please let me know if it is not working

```
 private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
 private NotificationManager mNotificationManager = null;
 private NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder;

 if (mNotificationManager == null) {
            mNotificationManager = (android.app.NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 }
 if (mNotificationBuilder == null) {
            mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_96x96)
                    .setContentText(getContentString(false, 0))
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setCategory(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 }
```

Comment: Why set the priority to be maximum ? Such things destroy what android is trying to achieve : "optimization".

Comment: sometimes it is necessary when devices as memory issues you might know it.

Comment: The point is the service in which you might have started your ongoing notification runs with foreground service priority level and if you set only notification to high priority, then even though service is killed in case of low memory issues, your notification is still running, which will be doing nothing but wasting precious memory, so, really ask yourself before doing such things, do I really need to change priority ?

Comment: Yes, you are right but the thing is that even if my service kills I can lunch app from my notification  and if service working it will be fine other wise new flow works as it is.

Comment: Yes, it is not a problem in any case, whether service is killed or not, the problem is : are we helping android os to save memory in low memory situations ?, Workflow will never get affected by setting higher priority for notifications, I agree with you on that.

Comment: I hope this inspired you to work more towards asking questions like, whether we really need to use any of the resource provided to us by android in our app. Help others too, if they do the same !

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..!

```
void notifyme(String string){

String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                                            getSystemService(ns);

int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;        // icon from resources
CharSequence tickerText = string + " Program Running...";     // ticker-text
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         // notification time
Context context = getApplicationContext();      // application Context
CharSequence contentTitle = *********;  // expanded message title
CharSequence contentText = string + " Program Running...";//expanded msg text

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                            this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

// the next two lines initialize the Notification, using the configurations
// above
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
                                                            contentIntent);
final int HELLO_ID = 1;
mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
}
```

After add this

```
final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: Can you plz explain, what is the difference between your code and problem code ?

Comment: sorry @atman-bhatt, Notification is almost deprecated, I have used NotificationCompat.Builder in my code :-)